# Data.com API query to Base CRM

Tags: rest, salesforce, crm, soql

Looking in at the DATA.com API we do have a license for 1000 API queries a day. My question is we are looking at a different CRM to handle our outbound sales processes other than SalesForce.

Base CRM looks like it is capable of handling our needs for our business and account processes. Is it possible to have the Base API send queries to the Data.com API and return the results?

I also see there is an API purchase within the SalesForce API. When you conduct a search API query does it require you to purchase the results if you have a license already in place to use Data.com?

Our goal is to have a primary CRM pull information from Data.com or another source for lead information and display it in the new CRM.

If none of this is possible with the solution I am looking at might you suggest other platforms.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't currently offer the triggers to query Data.com's database. However, there are a couple of other ways to integrate Data.com with Base. You can either use a polling-driven trigger to Data.com, you could attempt to configure a workflow in Data.com to send this data over to Base, or you could use an import to pull this data into Base (as many of our customers have done). I hope that helps!